# Sorting Messages with GroupWise API

Tags: novell, groupwise

Is it possible to sort GroupWise messages with the object API?

I know about filters and queries, however I couldn't find any sorting operators for filter and query expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use a cursor from what I can tell (short of loading everything).

```php
<?php

/* $this is a class that extends SoapClient using the groupwise.wsdl */
$q = (object)[
    'folderType' => 'Mailbox',
    'view' => 'count unreadCount'
];

$folder = $this->getFolderRequest($q);

$q = (object)[
    'container' => $folder->folder->id,
    'view' => 'subject peek noDownload'
];

$cursor = $this->createCursorRequest($q);

$q = (object)[
    'container' => $data->folder->id,
    'cursor' => $cursor->cursor,
    'position' => 'end',
    'count' => 20,
    'forward' => TRUE
];

$msgs = $this->readCursorRequest($q);

var_dump($msgs);

/* You could also throw readCursorRequest() in a loop and track offset + position for more intensive purposes */
?>
```

More reading: https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/groupwise_sdk/gwsdk_gwwebservices/data/b7m3i3x.html

Comment: oops! sorry I misread, I thought this was for the web services.